# Convert Python for loop to while loop with a counter

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, iteration, counter

I have an assignment for a python class that is asking to convert a for loop to a while loop that contains a counter in it, so that it will cut off when a list when it reaches a certain length. Unfortunately the assignment and the lessons leading up to it haven't really made it clear how to do this (and I know that it's something that isn't really necessary to do a lot in python since these kinds of programs are typically better with for loops anyways).

Here is the original code:

```
a = [7,12,9,14,15,18,12]
b = [9,14,8,3,15,17,15]
big = [ ]
for i in range ( len (a)):
        big.append ( max (a [i], b [i] ))
```

I'm also not exactly sure what this for loop is doing to begin with.. It seems like the output that is given is an alternating series of pairs of numbers from each of these original lists.

The output it gives is (when asked to print 'big') this:

```
[9, 14, 9, 14, 15, 18, 15]
```

The closest I've gotten to solving this and converting it to a while loop is this:

```
a = [7,12,9,14,15,18,12]
b = [9,14,8,3,15,17,15]
big = [ ]

i = 0

while i <= 8:
    i += 1
    big.append ( max (a [i], b [i] ))
    print(big)
```

However, the final output of this is actually:

```
[14, 9, 14, 15, 18, 15]
```

Which is for some reason only 6 numbers when it should be 7, and not the exact same series of numbers either.. The instructions for this assignment weren't written well and I'm pretty confused about this, any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Which number is missing? What happens to it?

Comment: In addition to that other guy: [PythonTutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) is a nice tool to follow the execution of short scripts.

Comment: When `i==0` you append `max(a[0], b[0])`, when `i==1` you append `max(a[1], b[1])`. etc. So the output isn't alternating between `a` and `b` - it's made up from those maximums

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are incrementing the value of `i` at the beginning of the while loop. Increment it at the end. You are skipping the first. Also you need to check your loop guard. You only have 7 elements in the list. I would change it to `i < len(a)`. Something like this

```
while i < len(a):
    big.append ( max (a [i], b [i] ))
    i += 1
print(big)
[9, 14, 9, 14, 15, 18, 15]
```

This is dependent on the asumption that length of a and b is equal

Comment: thank you so much! careless error on my part. much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment `i` after the statements using the current value in the loop have finished.

Also, I would continue to use `len()` in the while statement like so:

```
a = [7,12,9,14,15,18,12]
b = [9,14,8,3,15,17,15]
big = [ ]

i = 0

while i < len(a):
    big.append ( max (a [i], b [i] ))
    i += 1

print(big)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a manual counter

```
a = [7,12,9,14,15,18,12]
b = [9,14,8,3,15,17,15]
big = [ ]

i = 0
while i < len(a):
        big.append ( max (a [i], b [i] ))
        i+=1
```